# PyQt5 pyqtgraph (adding/removing) curves in a single plot

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm new to pyqt5 and am just looking for some direction.

In a single pyqtgraphics PlotItem Graph I would like to add/remove configurable PlotCurveItems.
I started with QWidgetList items but it seems that will not provide me the ability to add the same ListItem->functions with multiple configurations.

As a next step I'm looking at using Parameter Trees but am not sure if I am just making things more complicated.
Ultimately I would like to use the PlotItem.addItem() to run a configurable function/method and view a list of Items I have added that I can remove or reconfigure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find what you are looking for here:

```
import pyqtgraph.examples
pyqtgraph.examples.run()
```

basically you create your plot as follow:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import* 
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self.p = []
        self.c = []
        for i in range(3):
            self.p.append(self.win.addPlot(row=i, col=0))
            for j in range(2):
                self.c.append(self.p[-1].plot(np.random.rand(100), pen=3*i+j))
        self.update()
        self.del_curve()
        self.add_curve()

    def update(self): # update a curve
        self.c[3].setData(np.random.rand(100)*10)

    def del_curve(self): # remove a curve
        self.c[5].clear()

    def add_curve(self): # add a curve
        self.c.append(self.p[2].plot(np.random.rand(100)))

def startWindow():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWidget()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startWindow()
```

Comment: Thanks. With the curve variable being set, how would you be able to delete just that variable? Just using the standard `del variable`? That's why I was looking at using addItem()/removeItem() under the PlotItem class.

Comment: [curve].clear() just clear line display, legend still show that line's data, you need call removeItem() to totally remove line data